# AJAX on open and on change xmlhttp.open

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have created the below code which should on load, dump the document visible state to a mysql database via xmlhttp.open and .send.

The code does not execute as desired on open, but functions as expected with switching tabs, minimizing browser, etc.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
//Identify if visible or not
function handleVisibilityChange() {
var state = 'Visable'; 

 if (document.hidden) {    
    var state = 'Hidden';
  } else  {    
    var state = 'Visable';
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET","./track2.php?state="+state,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}

document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This file is being loaded as an include in a number of php pages, sort of stats tracker for the site.

Comment: What is the desired behavior?

Comment: To dump the visible state of the page to the mysql database.